# Changing category base breaks permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I'm trying to set permalinks structure in an SEO friendly way.
My team told me to set this permalink structure for posts:
/blog/%category%/%postname%/

It all works just fine when category base is: category

But we need it to be: blog

When I set it up as blog, posts return 404 status. Any idea why this might be? How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Where you set category base?

Comment: On category base field. Anyways I've found a solution. Category base had to have "/." at the end in order to prevent this 404 error.